# Why does the BERT encoder have an intermediate layer between the attention and neural network layers with a bigger output?

Tags: deep-learning, natural-language-processing, papers, attention, bert

I am reading the BERT paper [BERT: Pre-training of Deep Bidirectional Transformers for Language Understanding](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.04805.pdf).

As I look at the attention mechanism, I don't understand why in the BERT encoder we have an intermediate layer between the attention and neural network layers with a bigger output ($4*H$, where $H$ is the hidden size).
Perhaps it is the layer normalization, but, by looking at the code, I'm not certain.

Comment: I am thinking about the same. did you find out why is it there

Answer (score 2):

The paper [Undivided Attention: Are Intermediate Layers Necessary for BERT?](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.11881) should answer it.

In the abstract, they write

> All BERT-based architectures have a self-attention block followed by a block of intermediate layers as the basic building component. However, a strong justification for the inclusion of these intermediate layers remains missing in the literature.

In the conclusion, they write

> In this work we proposed a modification to the BERT architecture focusing on **reducing the number of intermediate layers in the network.** With the modified BERTBASE network **we show that the network complexity can be significantly decreased while preserving accuracy on fine-tuning tasks.**

Comment: So, why are "these intermediate layers" used? You're quoting the abstract that says that an explanation in the literature is missing, but do the authors of this paper provide it?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).